# How to change the angle of an object after collision in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In my game two objects are colliding with each other, but i want to change the angle of the object 
after collision with another object. I want the object to change its direction to 180 degrees after collision, i have used physics for collision,  Any help or suggestion.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get x,y components for the body's linear velocity using:

```
vx, vy = myBody:getLinearVelocity()
```

and reset it as:

```
myBody:setLinearVelocity(-vx,-vy )
```

For more info, visit [Corona - Physics Bodies](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-physics-bodies).

**Sample:**

```
local physics = require( "physics" )
physics.start()

-- Create ground and bodies ---
local ground = display.newImage( "ground.png" )
ground.x = display.contentWidth / 2
ground.y = 445
ground.myName = "ground"

local crate1 = display.newCircle(0,0,30,30)
crate1.x = 180; crate1.y = 350
crate1.myName = "first crate"

local crate2 = display.newCircle(0,0,30,30)
crate2.x = 220; crate2.y = -50
crate2.myName = "second crate"

-- physics.setDrawMode( "debug" ) -- Uncomment this line to see the physics shapes

-- Adding physics --
physics.addBody( ground, "static", { friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 } )
physics.addBody( crate1, { density=3.0, friction=0.5, bounce=0.3,radius = 30} )
physics.addBody( crate2, { density=3.0, friction=0.5, bounce=0.3,radius = 30} )

crate1:setLinearVelocity( 0, -400 )

-- Collision function --
local function onGlobalCollision( event )
  if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
    print(event.object1.myName .. " & " .. event.object2.myName .. " collision began" )
    vx_1, vy_1 = crate2:getLinearVelocity()     -- get the velocities of crate2
    crate2:setLinearVelocity(-vx_1,-vy_1 )      -- reset the velocities of crate2

    vx_2, vy_2 = crate1:getLinearVelocity()     -- get the velocities of crate1
    crate1:setLinearVelocity(-vx_2,-vy_2 )      -- reset the velocities of crate1
  end   
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onGlobalCollision )
```

Keep Coding.............. :)

Comment: This solution did'nt worked for me i tried it. Can you please tell me where to include this code or give a link for this type of solution. In my example both the bodies are colliding as they are physics body, after colliding the other body is moving in any direction, but i want it to move to 180 degree, it does not matter at which part it has collided..

Comment: Thanks for the help.. the above code works for me but i want some modifications, in this example both the balls move but i want one static and the other will move and collide after colliding it will change angle and if i want the ball move to an angle 90 degree rather than 180 degree what changes should i make in this code...

Comment: Just comment the line: 'crate1:setLinearVelocity( 0, -400 )' will make one ball static.

Comment: After collision, you can set 'crate1:setLinearVelocity(vx,vy), where vx and vy are xVelocity and yVelocity resp. eg: crate1:setLinearVelocity(-90,0 ).